# Бесконечный цикл , с последовательным выводом элементов

Tags: javascript, циклы

посмотрите пожалуйста код, тут выводит по по одному элементу массива, а как сделать чтобы к примеру по 2 элемента выводилось

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        let start = 0
        let end = arr.length - 1
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            
            console.log(arr[start])
            if(start === end || start > end) {
            
                start = 0;
                
            } else {
                start += 1;
            }
           
          }, 1000);
          return () => clearInterval(timer);
```

`

Comment: По 2 одинаковых или разных?) это очень важный момент

Comment: сейчас так  1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7  и по кругу , а надо 1,2 - 3,4 - 5,6 - 7 и по кругу

Comment: все делается проще. почитайте про shift, и push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тоже хочу предложить решение

```
function f(arr, size, fn, interval) {
    let
        pos = 0,
        timer = setInterval(() => {
            let chunk = [];
            if (arr.length && size > 0) {
                let
                    end = (pos + size) % arr.length,
                    mult = Math.floor((pos + size) / arr.length);
                chunk = mult ? arr.slice(pos) : arr.slice(pos, end);
                while (mult--) {
                    chunk = chunk.concat(mult ? arr : arr.slice(0, end));
                }

                pos = end;
            }

            fn(chunk);
        }, interval);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
}
f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2, console.log, 1000);
// f([], 2, console.log, 1000);
// f([1, 2, 3], 0, console.log, 1000);
// f([1, 2, 3], 1, console.log, 1000);
// f([1, 2, 3], 3, console.log, 1000);
// f([1, 2, 3], 4, console.log, 1000);
// f([1, 2, 3], 10, console.log, 1000);
```

Попробуйте разобраться как работает — это интересно и полезно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, обязательно ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение,  cначала делаем chunk

```
const arr:any = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    const perChunk = 2 
    const chunk = arr.reduce((resultArray:any, item:any, index:any) => { 
        const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index/perChunk)
      
        if(!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
          resultArray[chunkIndex] = []
        }
      
        resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)
      
        return resultArray
      }, [])

    let start = 0
    let end = chunk.length - 1

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        
        console.log(chunk[start])
        if(start === end || start > end) {
            start = 0;    
        } else {
            start ++;
        }

      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: как же вы усложнили свое решение для такой простой задачи :0 в вашем изначальном коде нужно было дописать всего пару строк  :) а именно - засунуть содержимое функции таймера в цикл ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function func() {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let start = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        let end = (start + 1) % arr.length;
        console.log(arr[start]+','+arr[end]);
        start = (start + 2) % arr.length;
    }, 1000);
    //return () => clearInterval(timer);
}

func()
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ